# Discord.js issues with default member permissions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to restrict the use of a slash command using the *setDefaultMemberPermissions* attribute that is supposed to take permission and then check to see if a user meets the requirements to execute a command however for some reason I cannot get the permissions to work

As shown in the official documentation I did the following:

```
const { PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');

new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('e')
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers),
```

this resulted in an undefined error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BanMembers')

Comment: What is your DJS version?

Comment: ive installed discord.js 13.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking at the current version of discord.js documentation.
For slash command permissions in v13 you need to import `PermissionFlagsBits` from a separate place:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord-api-types/v10');

const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ban')
    .setDescription('Ban a member!')
    .addUserOption(option =>
        option.setName('target').setDescription('The member to ban'))
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.KickMembers | PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers);
```

[see v13 docs](https://v13.discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#slash-command-permissions)